# Using xargs with find

Tags: command-line, find, xargs

I want to exclude some directories from searching files and than run the find command to find required files. I am using below command

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d | grep -E -i 'sensors' | grep -v '.test' | xargs find -name '*.java'
```

But it throws following error

```
find: paths must precede expression
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first find will cause the second find to list everything twice unless you exclude the current directory as well. This happens because the output of the first find contains a period.

```
$ find -maxdepth 1 -type d -print0 |
   grep -z -v -Ee 'sensors|\.test' |
   xargs.exe -0 -I% find % -name '*.java' |
   sort
  ./dirz/3.java
  ./dirz/3.java
  ./foo/2.java
  ./foo/2.java
  ./moo/1.java
  ./moo/1.java
```

You're better off doing something like this instead:

```
$ find . -type f -name \*java | grep -v -Ee './(sensors|\.test)'
./dirz/3.java
./foo/2.java
./moo/1.java
```

Or even:

```
$ echo dirz foo moo | tr \  \\n  > .search-dirs

$ find `cat .search-dirs` -type f -name \*java
dirz/3.java
foo/2.java
moo/1.java
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `xargs`' `-i` option which like in `find`'s `-exec` option replaces `{}` with the paths.

```
... | xargs -i find "{}" -name '*.java'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it directly in `find`; no need to involve `grep` or `xargs`.

With a directory structure like:

```
$ ls *
a_sensors_directory:
my_file.java  my_non_java_file.txt

a_sensors_directory.test:
my_file.java  my_non_java_file.txt

something_else:
my_file.java  my_non_java_file.txt
```

, this `GNU find` command will pick out files ending in `.java` in directories in the current working directory that contain the word `sensors`, but does not end in `.test` (if I interpreted your question correctly):

```
$ find -type f -ipath './*sensors*' -not -ipath './*.test/*' -iname '*.java'
./a_sensors_directory/my_file.java
```

`man find` should explain the switches clearly and probably better than I would.

Piping is powerful, but the base tools handle many scenarios by themselves in a more straightforward manner. This avoids unnecessary process forks and keeps subtle errors to a minimum.